# save downloaded track to SDCard?

Tags: android, mediastore

my problem is the Saved mp3 file has no duration and the title not appear

the Title sent to MediaStor from Json String

how i can save downloaded mp3 file as music ?

this is the code aim using now

```
File  k = new File(full_path);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, json.getString("title"));
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "my App");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM, "my App");
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION,false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
                values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);
                context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried to update the MediaStore.Audio directly.

Instead I add new mp3 files to the music collection by invoking the media scanner service directly which rescans all media files on the external storage

```
 sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
       Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`
```

Comment: but its will not show album title and artist its will show it as unknown right ??

Comment: it will only show informations which are in the mp3-file-tags. if mp3-file has no album-tag the android media database will not have this info as well. have you checked on a pc that the mp3-tags are all set as expected?

Comment: no i didn't my app download uploaded mp3 file by user , so i have to make album tag fixed album name , can i do it from PHP or android !

Comment: i dont know how to do it in php on the serverside. On android i experimented whith [myid3-for-android](http://sites.google.com/site/eternalsandbox/myid3-for-android) which requires jakarta-regexp-1.5.jar. I think it is easier to do the mp3-tag-ing on the serverside. Maybe your aproach with writing to the contentprovider of the MediaStore will be easier.